# How do I Switch to an in-memory store when running iOS app tests?

Tags: objective-c, ios, unit-testing, core-data

I have a pretty standard Xcode-generated interface for Core Data objects, namely these properties on my app delegate:

```
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

Now I'm writing application tests, but I want to use an in-memory database for core data that's reset every time a test runs. I've figured out a way to do it, but it feels totally hinky:

- I have a static variable, `storeType`, in the app delegate class.
- `-persistentStoreCoordinator` sets it to `NSSQLiteStoreType` if it's `nil`. This will be the default value and, in production, the *only* value, ensuring that things work properly when running the app.
- I make sure the the `DEBUG` macro is set for all debug builds (including for my App Tests target)
- If `DEBUG` is set, define a method in the app delegate, `-resetCoreData`. The method looks like this:

  ```
  #ifdef DEBUG
  - (void)resetCoreData {
      // Testing, we want to use the in memory store.
      storeType = NSInMemoryStoreType;

      // Disconnect core data.
      __persistentStoreCoordinator = nil;
      __managedObjectContext = nil;

      // Set up defaults.
      [self configureCoreDataDefaults];
  }
  #endif
  ```

  Note that it sets the static variable `storeType` to `NSInMemoryStoreType`. The `-configureCoreDataDefaults` method creates some managed objects that should always be present.
- In my app test base class, I have `-setup` call `-resetCoreData`:

  ```
  - (void)setUp {
      [super setUp];
      [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] resetCoreData];
  }
  ```

This gives me what I want: A fresh core data store with default objects created for every single test method.

But it's annoying. I've essentially added knowledge of the testing environment to my app delegate, to make it behave differently when running app tests. Gross!

So, what's a better way to do this? How do *you* do it?

Comment: Could you assume that Core Data is working and use a mock storage for the tests? Do you really need to test Core Data?

Comment: By using in-memory model, I've achieved the same effect as mocking core data: the data ends up in memory after each call, so I can then check to see if it looks correct. Actually mocking Core Data would require a great deal more work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend creating a DAO or similar to isolate the Core Data setup. Then, using a category, you can define and use this "resetCoreData" in your test target.

Comment: Usine a category is a good idea (why do I keep forgetting about them??), but I don't know what you mean by a DAO (data access object, I presume). Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, a Data Access Object. It's just an object with the CoreData logic. I just prefer adding a category to a DAO instead of adding a category to my main delegate. Also, my delegates tends to shrink a lot when I do that (the old "split-your-application-in-layers" thing :).

Comment: So the problem with that is that `-resetCoreData` mainly sets some private ivars to `nil`. I don't see an easy way to do that from a category. I want the properties to remain read-only for safe use. Need to think about it some more, though.

Comment: Okay, accepted, but I have added my own answer with the details on how I made it actually work. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 4):

A followup to @eduardo-costa's answer, which I have accepted, with the code I used to make it work.

First, I created a DAO class and moved all of the core data properties there. The .h file looks like this:

```
@interface CollectionsDAO : NSObject

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

+ (CollectionsDAO *)defaultDAO;

@end
```

Now I just use this class wherever I need to access my core data stuff. `-defaultDAO` returns a static instance of the class, so that I can just use one everywhere. What you don't see is a private instance method, `-storeType`, which returns `NSSQLiteStoreType`. This is used to create the store. I'll come back to it below.

Next, I created a category on this class for use in tests. The header file:

```
#import "CollectionsDAO.h"

@interface CollectionsDAO (Test)

+ (void)setupTestDAO;
+ (void)clearData;

@end
```

And the implementation:

```
#import "CollectionsDAO+Test.h"
#include <objc/runtime.h>

static CollectionsDAO *testDAO;
@implementation CollectionsDAO (Testing)

+ (CollectionsDAO *)testDAO {
    if (testDAO == nil) testDAO = [[self alloc] init];
    return testDAO;
}

+ (void)setupTestDAO {
    method_setImplementation(
        class_getClassMethod(self.class, @selector(defaultDAO)),
        method_getImplementation(class_getClassMethod(self.class, @selector(testDAO)))
    );
}

+ (void)clearData {
    testDAO = nil;
}

- (NSString *)storeType {
    return NSInMemoryStoreType;
}

@end
```

Note that `-storeType` replaces the default, private method of the same name, returning `NSInMemoryStoreType`, so that the data will be stored in memory.

Now, in my my testing base class, I just use this category like so:

```
#import "CollectionsDAO+Test.h"

@implementation AppTestBase
+ (void)initialize {
    if (self == AppTestBase.class) {
        [CollectionsDAO setupTestDAO];
    }
}
- (void)tearDown {
    [CollectionsDAO clearData];
}
@end
```

And now the test always uses memory for storing core data data, the test instance of the DAO is always returned by `+defaultDAO` (because `+setupTestDAO` swizzles it into place), and the core data is cleared after every test.

I think that this is a *lot* cleaner than what I had before. It took me a while to get it figured out, but Eduardo's answer was correct, I just had to work at it for a while to figure out the details.